# Keil creates 'faulty' hex file when one of the functions/macros is in the code

Tags: c, arm, stm32, keil

I'm in the process of transferring the code from STM32L0 to STM32L4. The project was working fine on the L0 but on the L4 when one of the functions is used then... the processor is going immediately into hard fault, straight away after I turn the debug session on (I even don't have to start the program, it starts it immediately and goes into hard fault).
The weird things:

- The function that causes the problem is actualy the macro in the `__STATIC_INLINE void LL_SPI_Enable(SPI_TypeDef *SPIx)` from `stm32l4xx_ll_spi.hex: SET_BIT(SPIx->CR1, SPI_CR1_SPE)`.
- The `.s` file which uses the the `LL_SPI_Enable()` is not created when I comment out that line containing the function. When the function is there it creates the `.s` file from the `.c` file which uses the function.
- The `LL_SPI_Enable()` function exists in many other places and it is fine. There is only one of my functions (defined as static inline `__attribute__((__always_inline__))` ) in one file which causes that weird behaviour. There are other functions doing the same thing (turning the SPI on) using the same `LL_SPI_Enable()` and those are not a problem. It looks like there is only one of my functions which cannot use `LL_SPI_Enacle()`
- The function to disable SPI doesn't cause any issues.
- The program doesn't hit even first line of the code, it goes into hard fault immediately.

I thought the scatter file was the problem so I used the default config for my CPU and the result is the same. I also tried different optimization levels and also no change. I don't have any errors from compiler or linker.

Did anybody have something like that?

Comment: That's a weird one!  Could you try to diagnose the cause of the hard fault?  Hard faults don't just happen, they're escalations of other fault types, which occur if the handler for the specific fault is not enabled or if the handler itself faults.  A really helpful first step would be to find out what kind of fault was actually generated.

Comment: I cannot, the weirdest thing is that when I have correctly working version I need to start the program in the debugger but when I have that 'broken version' it starts the program immediately and lands in the hard fault...

Comment: No reason to assume that the code will port from one chip to another.

Comment: if it faults "immediately" then the first thing to look at is your vector table.

Comment: You can prevent escalation to a hard fault by ensuring that all other fault types have correctly defined and enabled handlers that don't themselves fault.

Comment: I don't assume it will port without editing it. Do you think I took the code and I expect it will work? I have changed plenty things and the code works. There is just one line which causes that problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing "weird" in it.

If you land immediately (ie before the main function is called) there are usually three possible problems:

1. Linker file not for your micro
2. Startup files not for your micro
3. Wrong register addresses (wrong header files used)

In keil see in the Peripherals -> Core Peripherals -> Fault report.

You will see there the registers and the address of the place there the HF occurred and other information (depending on the actual HF source)

Further reading: www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt209.pdf